# ASP.NET Web API disable formatting of strings with ISO 8601 date format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET Web API app I have this model where `Dictionary<string,string> Data` has, among others, two `string` properties formatted with ISO 8601 date format, while `CreatedDate` and `LastUpdated.Date` are `DateTime`:

```
{
    "MemberId": "156358985",
    "Data": {
        "memberId": "22219665",
        "fullName": "First Lastname",
        "startTime": "2018-05-06T10:00:00.0000000+02:00",
        "endTime": "2018-05-06T10:30:00.0000000+02:00",
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2018-05-02T08:31:56.4846309+02:00",
    "LastUpdated": {
        "Date": "2018-05-02T08:31:56.4846309+02:00",
        "Epoch": 1525249916
    }
}
```

In the endpoint this looks like:

```
{
    "memberId": "156358985",       
    "data": {
        "memberId": "22219665",
        "fullName": "First Lastname",
        "startTime": "05/06/2018 10:00:00",
        "endTime": "05/06/2018 10:30:00"
    },
    "createdDate": "2018-05-02T08:31:56.4846309+02:00",
    "lastUpdated": {
        "date": "2018-05-02T08:31:56.4846309+02:00",
        "epoch": 1525249916
    }
}
```

I want `start/endTime` to be formatted in ISO 8601 date format and not the localized one.
So... How can I disable this auto formatting of strings having a date format?

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution or only for this particular problem?

Comment: I would prefer a generic one, but a solution to solve this particular problem is also welcome. I don't see that this will be a big problem anywhere else in my solution.

Comment: Can you add the code which recieves the request for the endpoint?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen Do you mean client code? This is a issue in how the JSON serializer is formatting strings with a date format.